# Searching ASP.NET SQL DataSet for Postcode

Tags: sql, asp.net, dataset, sql-like

I am doing a project in ASP.NET that at one point searches a SQL database for a postcode using Datasets:

```
string postcode = "%" + searchTerm.Trim().Replace(' ', '%') + "%";
SearchDataSet.SearchCustomerTableDataTable custTable = custAdapter.GetDataCustPostcode(postcode);
```

The `GetDataCustPostcode` runs:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE (CustomerPostcode LIKE @CustPostcode)
```

The expected results are returned when I try:

`searchTerm = "BT14"` searches for a `postcode` of %BT14%

or `searchTerm = "BT14 7"` searches for a `postcode` of %BT14%7%

`custTable` is empty when I try:

`searchTerm = "BT14 7D"` searches for a `postcode` of %BT14%7D%

If I try writing a SQL query directly, i.e. typing:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerTable WHERE (CustomerPostcode LIKE '%BT14%7D%')
```

Then the expected results are returned.

Can anyone advise why this is? Is it something to do with the characters in the string?

Thanks

Clivest

Comment: That is strange! When I tried it this morning it worked. I havent modified the code at all. Maybe a reboot helped? Anyway, it is all working correctly now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the single-character wildcard, the underscore, for mid-string matching, and percents only on the ends of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I had to use a percentage in the middle because the postcode could be `BT147DT` or `BT14 7DT`. Is that right? Or is there another wildcard that would be more appropriate

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm glad, per your comment, that things are working for you. If you are interested in learning more about the different supported wildcards, check this out: http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-asarc/srg1100e/sqlref/@Generic__BookTextView/73386;pt=73946

Answer (score 0):

%7D **is** a special character in some circumstances... perhaps this one as well? Does the problem also happen for other combinations?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It also does it for `BT14 7E`, but not `BT14 9E`